# How to automatically display a matrix from a string in r-markdown?

Tags: r, matrix, r-markdown

To show you my problem. The program below should create two same matrices: [A|b]1 and [A|b]2.

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, warning=FALSE, comment = "", 
message=FALSE)
```

```{r} 
my_string<-"2x+5y-2z+2p=9;\\\\ 3x-2y+1z-3p=34;\\\\ -3x+3y+2z+4p=33;\\\\ 
2x+3y+4z+5p=125"

x1<-gsub('([[:punct:]]|\\s)([a-z])', '\\11\\2', my_string)
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,"[a-z]"," & ")
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,"=","| ")
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,"[+]","")
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,";\\\\"," ")
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,"[&]+[\\s]+[|]"," |")
x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,"[|]","&|&")
```
```{r}
eq1 <-  noquote(paste(x1))
```

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{[A|b]1} = \left[\begin{matrix}
`r eq1`
\end{matrix}\right] 
\end{equation*}
$$

$$\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{[A|b]2} =
\left[ \begin{matrix}
2 & 5 & -2 & 2  &|& 9 \\ 3 & -2 & 1 & -3  &|& 34 \\ -3 & 3 & 2 & 4  &|& 33 
\\ 2 
& 3 & 4 & 5  &|& 125
\end{matrix} \right] 
\end{equation*}
$$
````

The first using `r eq1` and the second by writing the eq1 string directly:

> 2 & 5 & -2 & 2  &|& 9 \ 3 & -2 & 1 & -3  &|& 34 \ -3 & 3 & 2 & 4  &|& 33 \ 2 
>    & 3 & 4 & 5  &|& 125

But the output is:
[image: matrix]
How can I solve this problem? I can't use the second version because the program has to work properly after I modify `my_string`.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Just delete this line `x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,";\\\\"," ")` and the `;;` in `my_string`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the line `r eq1` will output single "\" to the final result. Try to double the slash symbol.

In order to inspect your result, try to add the following YAML header:

```
---
output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes
---
```

And check the resulting `.md` file. You'll see that the two equation blocks are not the same, missing the double "\" in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

As @I. Brum already stated in his answer, in this case there are two backslashes `\\` needed in order to achieve the line break in your (directly written) matrix.

Technically it is just one backslash `\` which is escaped (i.e. prevented from been read as code directly), and the way to escape something in R is a backslash again `\`, thus we have to write two backslashes `\\` in order to express one `\`.

Hereby your `eq1` object includes a (regular) expression that is to be passed over to the rmarkdown math section, inserted at `` `r eq1` `` which is getting a bit more complicated. It is the same way as with *regular expressions*:

> "If \ is used as an escape character in regular expressions, how do you match a literal \? Well you need to escape it, creating the regular expression \\. To create that regular expression, you need to use a string, which also needs to escape . That means to match a literal \ you need to write "\\\\" — you need four backslashes to match one!" [(*Regular expressions* from CRAN, see section *Escaping*)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html)

So just delete the `x1<-stringr::str_replace_all(x1,";\\\\"," ")` line from your code (else it deletes just all of the backslashes) and you'll get your desired matrix.